# React-native/iOS app: Module 'SquareInAppPaymentsSDK' not found, although it has been added to the project

Tags: xcode, react-native-ios, square

#### For further information

- I have posted this also in https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/issues/66#issuecomment-623619907 - you can find more details there.
- The installation instructions of the package I am having problems with are in https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/docs/get-started.md

#### Summarizing the problem

- The problem I am having is that I have configured a react-native package ([react-native-square-in-app-payments](https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin)) in Xcode, but I am getting an error saying that 'module xxx not found'.

#### The question, is:

- Why doesn't Xcode find the 'missing' module? What is not configured properly? Where should I look to check?

#### The error is the following

`Module 'SquareInAppPaymentsSDK' not found`

[image]

#### My podfile:

```
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'myproject' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNSquareInAppPayments', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-square-in-app-payments'

  post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == 'React'
        target.remove_from_project
      end
    end
  end

end
```

#### My project.pbxproj file (couldn't attach it here, but you can access it in github):

https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/issues/66#issuecomment-625333601

#### Update: Linking (following the 1st comment and @DenisTsoi answer) below

I tried automatic linking (as noted, I need it since I am using RN 0.59.9), and then I started again and tried manual linking, for both I have the same error. You can see my comments about this in https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/issues/66#issuecomment-625330210

BTW, under 'link binary with libraries' I have two entries of the package:

- SquareInAppPaymentsSDK.framework (as requested in https://developer.squareup.com/docs/in-app-payments-sdk/installation#option-3-install-the-in-app-payments-sdk-manually)
- libRNSquareInApppayments.a (part of linking)

#### Comment to @MuhammadNuman answer below:

I tried your podfile in a new react-native project (created by react-init). When I add

```
import { SQIPCore } from 'react-native-square-in-app-payments';
```

I get the error described in https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/issues/66#issuecomment-629762613

You may find my repo in https://github.com/rahamin1/square_with-podfile

Comment: If you’re running rn 0.60+ the app should auto Link most rn dependencies, however pre 60+ you need to link it manually.

Comment: I know and I did, thank you!

Comment: did it help or no? - also did the answer below help?

Comment: Didn't. Just added few lines about it in the bottom of my question.

Comment: can you do us a favour and make a minimal repo (nothing else, just be able to reproduce this error on a separate example repo please) - it'll take us forever to set something up that wont be the same as your RN settings

Comment: I did create a minimal repo with 0.59.9 and it didn't have any problems... :(

Sure, upvoted. I appreciate the effort and your time.

My feeling, BTW, that an answer to the question written here may lead to the solution. Just a feeling... https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/issues/66#issuecomment-625898377

Comment: did you follow this step 3a or 3b?
https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/docs/get-started.md#step-3a-add-the-in-app-payments-sdk-to-your-ios-project-without-cocoapods

https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/blob/master/docs/get-started.md#step-3b-add-the-in-app-payments-sdk-to-your-ios-project-with-cocoapods

Comment: you might have to pod install if you haven't already

Comment: looks like youve installed it as well... hmmmmm

Comment: Right you are :)
I have been doing almost everything in the last 2 weeks. I am looking for a wizard who will find the problem in one of my configuration files (e.j project.pbxproj) and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have faced this type of error in the past. Because some configuration things were missing or broken which leads these type of issues. So my suggestion for you is to create a new react-native project install all the library in the package.json one by one from the NPM or GitHub document of there library. and then copy the code from src (React Code) into the new project. If you have any changes inside the ios and android folder then only copy the changes from the file and paste to the file of the new project android/ios folder. (If nothing works then apply this solution. it always works for me)

Comment: Seems that this is best advise I got so far. I will try it and update here.
I am marking this as the accepted answer, since the other one is something that I tried before posting the question (and it didn't work).

Comment: And, indeed, this solved the problem, but I am facing now another problem: https://github.com/square/in-app-payments-react-native-plugin/issues/66#issuecomment-629762613

Comment: @Yossi I think square app-payments-react-native-plugin have an issue with there library I was also getting the same issue.in.

Comment: Waiting for their response in the above github issue

Answer (score 2):

According to your github issue link,

You’re running react 0.59.x. This means you’ll be required to run

`react-native link`

For native libraries to be linked in iOS XCode.

An alternative method is linking the dependency in XCode, which can be found on the react native [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios)

Excerpt

> Step 1 If the library has native code, there must be an .xcodeproj
>   file inside its folder. Drag this file to your project on Xcode
>   (usually under the Libraries group on Xcode);

￼[image: step 1]

> Step 2 Click on your main project file (the one that represents the
>   .xcodeproj) select Build Phases and drag the static library from the
>   Products folder inside the Library you are importing to Link Binary
>   With Libraries

￼[image: step 2]

> Step 3 Not every library will need this step, what you need to
>   consider is: Do I need to know the contents of the library at compile
>   time? What that means is, are you using this library on the native
>   side or only in JavaScript? If you are only using it in JavaScript,
>   you are good to go! If you do need to call it from native, then we
>   need to know the library's headers. To achieve that you have to go to
>   your project's file, select Build Settings and search for Header
>   Search Paths. There you should include the path to your library. (This
>   documentation used to recommend using recursive, but this is no longer
>   recommended, as it can cause subtle build failures, especially with
>   CocoaPods.) ￼

[image: step 3]

For RN 0.60+ linking is done automatically.

**Edit:**

You can also install the SDK with cocoapods via the command in the directory `<YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY>/ios`

```
pod install
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried both. See the update to the question (few lines regarding linking at the bottom).

Comment: having a look - (bit difficult since there's no minimal example repo that can be cloned and reproduce)

Comment: Answered after your comment for the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also clone and test boilerplate for **react-native 0.59.9**

https://github.com/nomi9995/in-app-payments-0.59.9.git

change your podfile

```
platform :ios, '11.1'

target 'myproject' do
  use_frameworks!

  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
  'CxxBridge',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTWebSocket',
  'RCTAnimation',
  'RCTActionSheet',
  'RCTGeolocation',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTSettings',
  'RCTVibration',
  'RCTLinkingIOS'
  ]
  pod 'yoga', :path => "#{rn_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
  pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec'
  pod 'Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec'

  pod 'RNSquareInAppPayments', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-square-in-app-payments'


end
```

and install podfile againt

```
pod install
```

Comment: Thanks @MMuhammadNuman ! But I used the same RNSquareInAppPayments pod.

Comment: are you using pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [
  'CxxBridge',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTWebSocket',
  'RCTAnimation',
  'RCTActionSheet',
  'RCTGeolocation',
  'RCTImage',
  'RCTSettings',
  'RCTVibration',
  'RCTLinkingIOS'
  ]

Comment: can you check my boilerplate?

Comment: First of all, I would like to say that I appreciate your reply. Thank you! For 1st question: I am not using them. For the 2nd: I didn't, since my problem is not with boilerplates. I have a boilerplate with the 2 square plugins which is working. The problem is making it work with my app.

Comment: @Yossi please pod 'React', path: rn_path, subspecs: [ 'CxxBridge', 'RCTText', 'RCTNetwork', 'RCTWebSocket', 'RCTAnimation', 'RCTActionSheet', 'RCTGeolocation', 'RCTImage', 'RCTSettings', 'RCTVibration', 'RCTLinkingIOS' ]try this

Comment: See comment to this in my question, at the bottom.